# Why are the AJAX beforeSend and complete functions triggered multiple times when no options are set

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototype

I'm using a [jQuery Ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in a prototype function. I want the user to be able to pass his own `complete` and `beforeSend` functions into this function. These user-functions then should get extracted from the options and put into my own `beforeSend` and `complete` functions so I can do some system stuff in them before the user functions are triggered.

I made this fiddle to clarify. See how the link "With Options" is working as expected and the link "Without Options" is not. Click it several times to see what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/xwmoaepc/1/

```
function jBox() {
    this.options = {
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://stephanwagner.me/ajax/0/SYSTEM RESPONSE',
            data: ''
        }
    }
}

jBox.prototype.ajax = function (options) {

    $('#log').append('<div class="first">function prototype.ajax started<div>');

    // Abort running ajax call
    this.ajaxRequest && this.ajaxRequest.abort();

    // Merge options
    var ajaxOptions = jQuery.extend(this.options.ajax, (options || {}));

    // Extract events
    var beforeSend = ajaxOptions.beforeSend || function () {};
    var complete = ajaxOptions.complete || function () {};

    // Set new beforeSend event
    ajaxOptions.beforeSend = function () {

        $('#log').append('<div style="color: #d66">SYSTEM-beforeSend<div>');

        (beforeSend.bind(this))();
    }.bind(this);

    // Set new complete event 
    ajaxOptions.complete = function (response) {

        $('#log').append('<div style="color: #6d6">SYSTEM-complete: ' + response.responseText + '<div>');

        (complete.bind(this))(response);
    }.bind(this);

    // Send new ajax request
    this.ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax(ajaxOptions);
};

// Create instance
var jBox = new jBox();

// This function is working!
function triggerAjaxOpt() {

    var userOptions = {
        url: 'http://stephanwagner.me/ajax/0/USER RESPONSE: ' + $('input').val(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#log').append('<div style="color: #66d">USER-beforeSend<div>');
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#log').append('<div style="color: #66d">USER-complete<div>');
        }
    };

    jBox.ajax(userOptions);
}

// This function will have more and more beforeSend and complete outputs
function triggerAjax() {
    jBox.ajax();
}
```

Also note, that when you change the number 2 to 3 after you clicked the not working link, it will not change the response.

EDIT: It's working now, this is what i ended up with:
http://jsfiddle.net/xwmoaepc/3/

Comment: You're working on constant object jBox and you're extending it over and over without clearing values or unbinding events. That's why it stack them.

Comment: So you mean when I extend this.options.ajax, it will stack the functions rather than overwrite them?

Comment: you can bind as many events as you want. unless you unbind or override them they'll still be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and it'll work:

```
var ajaxOptions = jQuery.extend((options || {}), this.options.ajax);
```

If you have this.options.ajax as the first argument of extend it'll mutate this.options.ajax see code below:

```
//see what the following line does when second argument is an object
//  not having beforesend (if it has then it'll be overwritten)
//var ajaxOptions = jQuery.extend(this.options.ajax, (options || {}));
var org = {id:"org"}
var copy = jQuery.extend(org,{});
console.log(copy===org);//true as copy is a reference to org
copy.id="copy";//mutating members in copy affect org
console.log(org.id);//=copy
```

Now the statement:

```
ajaxOptions.beforeSend = function () { ...
```

is the same as:

```
this.options.ajax.beforeSend = function() { ...
```

So the first time it'll be undefined and the local variable beforeSend will be an empty function.

The second time the local variable beforeSend will be this.options.ajax.beforesend and this.options.ajax.beforesend is re assigned with a function that calls the local variable beforesend that will call the closure beforesent (empty function)

The third time you call ajax ...